# Sorting Backlog Items Within An Iteration

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to sort the items on the board by name?  It seems like they want to arrange themselves by their task number which isn't always useful...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that sorting within an iteration is driven by the **Backlog Priority** value.

[image]

This is a partial ordering, since the **Backlog Priorty** value does not need to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably write a tfs web access plugin to do this. These plugins are written in javascript and because jQuery is already included in the page it should be fairly trivial to do.

See Tiago Pascoal's taskboard enhancer for an example plugin.

http://pascoal.net/2012/12/team-foundation-task-board-enhancer-version-0-4-released/

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was able to figure out how to drive sorting of backlog items recently. Please see my answer as it might be of interest to you.